# Get mouse x & y in nested MouseArea with hoverEnabled

Tags: qt, qml, flickable, mousearea

I made a simplified MapImage component which allows to zoom and pan an image with the mouse. This component uses [Flickable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html) and [MouseArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html) components. The MapImage component just handles image display, zooming and panning. I want to use another MouseArea in the MapImage instance in main.qml (to be able to place objects using a Canvas but this is not important here). This is not the job of MapImage, so I really need this second MouseArea component.

I need to set the [hoverEnabled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#hoverEnabled-prop) property to true because I need [onPositionChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#positionChanged-signal) and others events... But this property seems to cause problems with [mouseX and mouseY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#mouseX-prop) values taken from my `updateFlickable` function. When I'm zooming with the mouse wheel, zoom does not occur at the mouse position...

I've made a minimal example available here or in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ardeidae/0e38317a6270fa9cbf52b57ac29bf29d).

Any hint to solve this?

**main.qml**

```
import QtQml.Models 2.11
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

MapImage {
    id: map
    height: 600
    width: 800

    imageSource: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1651634099253-720df02a0d50"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        hoverEnabled: true // this is required to use onPositionChanged
        preventStealing: false

        onPressed: {
            // needed for flickable
            mouse.accepted = false;
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            // do something.
        }

    }
}
```

**MapImage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11

Item {
    id: root
    property alias imageSource: image.source

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: props.originalImageWidth
        contentHeight: props.originalImageHeight

        Image {
            id: image
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

            onStatusChanged: {
                if (status === Image.Ready) {
                    props.originalImageWidth = sourceSize.width;
                    props.originalImageHeight = sourceSize.height;
                    props.changeCurrentScale(1);
                }
            }

            // define the image display size
            width: flickable.contentWidth;
            height: flickable.contentHeight;

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                hoverEnabled: true

                onWheel: {
                    wheel.accepted = false;
                    props.changeCurrentScale(wheel.angleDelta.y);
                }
            }
        }

        QtObject {
            id: props

            // original image size
            property int originalImageWidth
            property int originalImageHeight

            property real scaleStep: 0.2
            property real currentScale: 0.1

            onCurrentScaleChanged: updateFlickable(currentScale);

            function updateFlickable(scale) {
                console.log(mouseArea.mouseX, mouseArea.mouseY); // <------ I am no longer able to get mouse x and y coordinates
                flickable.resizeContent(originalImageWidth * scale, originalImageHeight * scale, Qt.point(mouseArea.mouseX, mouseArea.mouseY));
                flickable.returnToBounds();
            }

            function changeCurrentScale(wheelDelta) {
                if (wheelDelta > 0) currentScale = currentScale * (1 + scaleStep);
                else currentScale = currentScale / (1 + scaleStep);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `propogateComposedEvents` help you?

Comment: No, I tried in both mousearea, and no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. I had to add a new property in my MapImage component. This property role is to store the updated position of the mouse in the parent mouse area in the parent coordinate system. After that, I have to use mapToItem to convert in the flickable.contentItem coordinate system.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQml.Models 2.11
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

MapImage {
    id: map
    height: 600
    width: 800

    imageSource: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1651634099253-720df02a0d50"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        hoverEnabled: true // this is required to use onPositionChanged
        preventStealing: false

        onPressed: {
            // needed for flickable
            mouse.accepted = false;
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            // CHANGE HERE
            // the position must be updated on every position change
            map.parentMouseAreaPosition = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
            // TO HERE
        }
    }
}
```

**MapImage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11

Item {
    id: root
    property alias imageSource: image.source

    // CHANGE HERE
    // the current mouse position in the parent mouse area in parent coordinate system
    property var parentMouseAreaPosition: Qt.point(0, 0)

    // this function maps the parent coordinate system to that of contentItem
    function __mapToContentItem(x, y) {
        return mapToItem(flickable.contentItem, x, y);
    }
    // TO HERE

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: props.originalImageWidth
        contentHeight: props.originalImageHeight

        Image {
            id: image
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

            onStatusChanged: {
                if (status === Image.Ready) {
                    props.originalImageWidth = sourceSize.width;
                    props.originalImageHeight = sourceSize.height;
                    props.changeCurrentScale(1);
                }
            }

            // define the image display size
            width: flickable.contentWidth;
            height: flickable.contentHeight;

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                hoverEnabled: true

                onWheel: {
                    wheel.accepted = false;
                    props.changeCurrentScale(wheel.angleDelta.y);
                }
            }
        }

        QtObject {
            id: props

            // original image size
            property int originalImageWidth
            property int originalImageHeight

            property real scaleStep: 0.2
            property real currentScale: 0.1

            onCurrentScaleChanged: updateFlickable(currentScale);

            function updateFlickable(scale) {
                // CHANGE HERE
                // get the mapped point
                let point = __mapToContentItem(root.parentMouseAreaPosition.x, root.parentMouseAreaPosition.y);
                console.log(point.x, point.y);
                flickable.resizeContent(originalImageWidth * scale, originalImageHeight * scale, point);
                // TO HERE
                flickable.returnToBounds();
            }

            function changeCurrentScale(wheelDelta) {
                if (wheelDelta > 0) currentScale = currentScale * (1 + scaleStep);
                else currentScale = currentScale / (1 + scaleStep);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if there is a better solution.